# Combine TimeSeries Indicators for Predictive Power

Tags: optimization, data-mining

I'm beginning a data analytics project and am curious what the best approach is to handle the following scenario:

1 outcome variable (numerical),
4 predictor variables (all numerical),

There is no relationship (linear or non) between any of variables

Dataset in python:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.DataFrame( np.random.random([100,5])*100-50, columns=[['outcome','v1','v2','v3','v4']]  )​
```

Seeking a subset of v1-v4 that maximizes sum(outcome) with a min of 5 cases.
If there wasn't a minimum output constraint of 5, I'd simply find max(outcome) and whatever v1-v4 values were, i'd use those as my filters. But since I need multiple cases, I need to do a brute force search, I'm thinking of this as an optimization for classification data if that makes sense..

What is a good way to do this optimization search?

Also, please comment if anything is unclear.

Ben

Comment: added a dataset to help someone answer

Comment: Recently had a new thought - think of the outcome variable as numerical and the other variables as strings or classification values.  That might help setup the optimizer..